# Rpy2 can't find my R libraries on install

Tags: python, r, rpy2

R built from source, installed locally. R is at `~/bin/R` (which is in my PATH) and its libraries are in `~/lib64/R/`. Installing rpy2 should be simple. It finds the correct R just fine (as it's in the path). Then it can't find the libraries.

```
$python setup.py build install
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) -- "World-Famous Astronaut"

...

setup.py:211: UserWarning: No include specified
  warnings.warn('No include specified')
setup.py:222: UserWarning: No libraries as -l arguments to the compiler.
  warnings.warn('No libraries as -l arguments to the compiler.')

    Compilation parameters for rpy2's C components:
        include_dirs    = []
        library_dirs    = []
        libraries       = []
        extra_link_args = []
```

And then we get a million errors that it can't find functions that are in the R libraries.

Rpy2's [documentation says](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/overview.html) there's a simple option for designating where R or its libraries are:

```
python setup.py build --r-home ~/lib64/R/lib install
```

But if you do this, then you get:

```
setup.py:222: UserWarning: No libraries as -l arguments to the compiler.
  warnings.warn('No libraries as -l arguments to the compiler.')

    Compilation parameters for rpy2's C components:
        include_dirs    = []
        library_dirs    = []
        libraries       = []
        extra_link_args = []

usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: option --r-home not recognized
```

It looks like the `--r-home` functionality has been removed. How does one point rpy2 to the correct libraries?

---

Edit:

Have now installed R with:

```
./configure --prefix=${HOME} --enable-R-shlib
make
make install
```

After that, I can install rpy2 with just `pip install rpy2`. But then, we're still having library problems:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
ImportError: libRblas.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So then I needed to add this to my path:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="~/lib64/R/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

And then everything works!

Comment: @Hack-R Why? I don't see how that relates.

Comment: @Hack-R That is not what my question is about. I am asking about installing Rpy2, and how at installation it needs to know the location of R and its associated materials. At this point Rpy2 doesn't even install.

Comment: Did you compile R as a shared library ? Also, any reason you are not doing `pip install rpy2` ?

Comment: "Did you compile R as a shared library?" I do not know what you mean by that. I compiled it without root privileges, with everything in my ~/ directory. I'm not using `pip install rpy` because it produced the same error, and I thought that building from source would open up compilation options that I wouldn't otherwise have (like `--r-home`).

Comment: During the configuration step, use `./configure --enable-R-shlib`. I also see that you have `libRblas.so`, `libRlapacks.so`, but no `libR.so`. May be sharing precisely how you compiled R would give helpful hints about what might be happening...

Answer (score 2):

If R is in an unconventional location, the easiest might be help out a bit by setting environment variables (older versions of the doc is talking about `--r-home` but this was a less tested corner and it was removed).

Try:

```
export PATH=~/bin/R:${PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib64/R/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=~/lib64/R/lib/pkgconfig/:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried this, and it's the same behavior. The output still shows empty lists for the "Compilation parameters for rpy2's C components". Note: There is no `lib64/R/lib/pkgconfig` directory. All that's in `lib64/R/lib`  is `libRblas.so` and `libRlapack.so`

Comment: @lgautier's solution worked for me (without re-compilation of `R`). My specific problem was that I was using `Microsoft R open`. For my `MRO` version I changed `/etc/environment` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="your_old_stuff:/usr/lib64/MRO-3.2.3/R-3.2.3/lib/R/lib"`, `PATH="your_old_stuff:/usr/lib64/MRO-3.2.3/R-3.2.3/lib/R/bin"` and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH="your_old_stuff:/usr/lib64/MRO-3.2.3/R-3.2.3/lib/pkgconfig"`, with `your_old_stuff` denoting your old env variables. Might help someone with similar issues... Note that I was intentionally using `/etc/environment` as I have several users who call `Rpy2`.

Comment: @cryo111 : thanks for the note that rpy2 is also working with `Microsoft R Open` (I wanted to try out one day, and this since the Revolution Computing days, but never found the time to).

Answer (score 1):

I've had the best success building rpy2 with non-standard R locations using the following relative path during install:

```
export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,~/lib64/R/lib"
```

Note that you only need to export this in the terminal where you then run `python setup.py install` and not in your `.bashrc` or the like. It will store this library path in the rpy2 compiled parts.

This is imho a better option than `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which some consider evil:

https://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/avoiding_ld_library_path_the

http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/ld-lib-path.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to installing R for M1 Mac from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/

I also had to install wheel:

```py
pip install wheel
```

(see [Why is python setup.py saying invalid command 'bdist_wheel' on Travis CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819221/why-is-python-setup-py-saying-invalid-command-bdist-wheel-on-travis-ci))