# Why is python setup.py saying invalid command 'bdist_wheel' on Travis CI?

Tags: python, travis-ci, setup.py, pypi

My Python package has a `setup.py` which builds fine locally on Ubuntu Trusty and on a fresh Vagrant Ubuntu Trusty VM when I provision it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install python python-dev --force-yes --assume-yes --fix-broken
curl --silent --show-error --retry 5 https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python2.7
sudo -H pip install setuptools wheel virtualenv --upgrade
```

But when I do the same on a Travis CI Trusty Beta VM:

```
- sudo apt-get install python python-dev --force-yes --assume-yes --fix-broken
- curl --silent --show-error --retry 5 https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python2.7
- sudo -H pip install setuptools wheel virtualenv --upgrade
```

I get:

```
python2.7 setup.py bdist_wheel
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help
error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
```

This [Why can I not create a wheel in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664102/why-can-i-not-create-a-wheel-in-python) is related but note I am installing wheel and upgrading setuptools.

Answer (score 1465, accepted):

Had to install the `wheel` package. Everything was up to date but still giving the error.

```
pip install wheel
```

then

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

worked without issues.

Comment: I needed `pip3 install wheel` - because I already had wheel installed for `pip` but not `pip3`.

Comment: This worked but after `pip install wheel` I had to `pip uninstall -r requirements.txt` and redo `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: `can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @Cerin `pip install wheel` is sufficient.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically install `wheel` in a clean virtual environment? `python3 -m venv --system-site-packages` will add too much packages.

Comment: @TobiasSette If you are using `virtualenv` and not `venv` you can specify `virtualenv myvenv --wheel <VERSION>` with a valid version and it will make sure that is present in the `virtualenv` after creation.

Comment: perfer find the used python and execute /with/full/path/of/python -m pip install wheel

Answer (score 280):

On a AWS `Ubuntu 18.04 new machine`, below installations are required:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc libpq-dev -y
sudo apt-get install python-dev  python-pip -y
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip python3-venv python3-wheel -y
pip3 install wheel
```

Especially the last line is a must.
However before 3 lines might be required as prerequisites.

Comment: I was using `--no-install-recommends` in a Docker image ([DL3015](https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint/wiki/DL3015)) and running into this error, I needed to explicitly install `python3-wheel`. Thanks!

Comment: The last line should be a no-op, because wheel is already installed. Did you run it with `--upgrade`? If anyone's able to create a minimal Dockerfile starting from Ubuntu 18.04 that would be the gold standard.

Comment: I had to install also sudo apt install build-essential , because I had the same problem for pip3 install shap. Then it works!

Comment: I does make sense to `pip3 install wheel` inside virtual env. However installing it system wide with apt-get and then overriding it with pip doesn't. Or there is something more to it?

Comment: @mx0 I wasted a lot of time came out with the above combination, seems to work for all. Please feel free to add if you find some new info.

Comment: But why is this necessary? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 under WSL2, just starting a fresh env using venv. When installing numpy i get the error msg above (but it kind of works anyway?)

Comment: @Einar We all are like you faced the same issue & somehow solved it by trial and error. On why is it necessary? Those tool owners can tell, they should fix this as many people have the same issue.

Comment: @ManoharReddyPoreddy I don't believe this is being caused by the tool owners but the ubuntu package maintainer.  `bdist_wheel` is [listed](https://github.com/pypa/wheel/blob/b8c4aa055cea0132776e7e53edce3538710d5b68/setup.cfg#L53) as an entry point by the wheel package.  So installing it should put the command in your path.  However the ubuntu package `python3-wheel` doesn't have contain `/usr/bin/bdist_wheel` or any entry point.  Files listed here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/python3-wheel/filelist

Answer (score 120):

```
pip install wheel
```

worked for me, but you can also add this

```
setup(
    ...
    setup_requires=['wheel']
)
```

to setup.py and save yourself a pip install command

Comment: Those people already have wheel installed and still getting the error can add `setup_requires=['wheel']` to get rid of this error

Comment: This does not work as expected:

1 - at first it works only because we've installed `wheel` with pip. It will fail again in a clean installation
2 - [documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) says "Note: projects listed in setup_requires will NOT be automatically installed on the system where the setup script is being run."

Comment: Not only that, @TobiasSette, but that same documentation link says:
"Warning Using setup_requires is discouraged in favor of PEP-518."

Comment: @JeffWright it might be discouraged but this was the ONLY way that I could run `python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal` in a virtualenv where I had specifically uninstalled `wheel` to test. I believe the `setup_requires` triggers `easy_install` to grab `wheel` which causes it to not show up in `pip list` but you can see it in the `.eggs` folder. Since this is a local only copy of wheel it can be useful if you can't `pip install wheel` or have trouble with `pip install --user wheel`.

Comment: How can I install setup_requires? using `python setup.py bdist_wheel `?

Answer (score 72):

If you already have all the required modules installed you probably need to import the `setuptools` module in your `setup.py` file. So just add the following line at the leading of `setup.py` file.

```
import setuptools
from distutils.core import setup
# other imports and setups
```

This is also mentioned in wheel's documentation. https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#usage

Comment: This worked for me.  I was using distutils instead of setuptools for the setup and I already had the wheel package installed.

Answer (score 56):

This problem is due to:

- an old version of pip (6.1.1) being installed for Python 2.7
- multiple copies of Python 2.7 installed on the Trusty Beta image
- a different location for Python 2.7 being used for `sudo`

It's all a bit complicated and better explained here https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4989.

My solution was to install with user `travis` instead of `sudo`:

```
- pip2.7 install --upgrade --user travis pip setuptools wheel virtualenv
```

Comment: In my case, `sudo -H pip install setuptools --upgrade` solved the problem.

Comment: @MartinThoma Thanks for your tip. It worked for me after issuing `sudo -H pip install wheel --upgrade`

Comment: Upgrading pip was enough in my case, from 9.0.1 to 20.0.2

Answer (score 47):

in my case, the version of wheel/pip/setuptools created by venv is too old.
this works:

```
venv/bin/pip  install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
```

Answer (score 37):

This error is weird as many proposed answers and got mixed solutions. I tried them, add them. It was only when I added `pip install --upgrade pip` finally removed the error for me. But I have no time to isolate which is which,so this is just fyi.

Answer (score 23):

In your `setup.py`, if you have:

```
from distutils.core import setup
```

Then, change it to

```
from setuptools import setup
```

Then re-create your virtualenv and re-run the command, and it should work.

Comment: This fixes my problem. Thank you. +1

Comment: This should be the answer. Thank you

Comment: This shoud be answer +1

Answer (score 19):

I already had `wheel` installed so I tried to uninstall and reinstall, and it fixed the issue:

```
pip uninstall wheel
pip install wheel
```

Weird...

Comment: FWIW I just encountered this error and uninstalling and re-installing worked for me

Comment: I ran `pip install wheel` from an activated virtualenv which fixed it, but the fix persisted after removing and recreating the virtualenv, which makes no sense. I would have expected any effects of `pip install wheel` to go away with the virtualenv.

Answer (score 15):

My fix was `apt install python3-dev`

Comment: Yes, and add `setup_requires=["wheel"]` to your setup.py

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps, your pip version is outdated. I experienced the same problem in WSL while installing modules in a newly created virtual environment. I was able to resolve it by running the following command:

```sh
$ ./bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 9):

I did `apt-get install python3-dev` in my Ubuntu and added `setup_requires=["wheel"]` in `setup.py`

Comment: It may be enough to run `pip install wheel`.

Comment: Where is `setup.py` supposed to be located? In other words: which `setup.py`?

Answer (score 6):

Try modifying the setup.py file by importing setup from setuptools instead of distutils.core

Comment: Worked for me! I was migrating a package from Python2 to Python3 and unfortunately couldn't find a guide for that. Anyone doing the same and getting frustrated with this problem, this might do it for you!

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `setup.cfg` files, add this before the `install_require` part:

```
setup_requires =
    wheel
```

---

Example of setup.cfg project :

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup()
```

```
# setup.cfg
[metadata]
name = name
version = 0.0.1
description = desc
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = url
author = author
classifiers =
    Programming Language :: Python
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3

[options]
include_package_data = true
packages = find:
setup_requires =
    wheel
install_requires =
    packages
    packages
    packages
```

Answer (score 3):

It helped me to follow instructions in here:

https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/

**Debian/Ubuntu**

Python 2:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

Python 3:

```
sudo apt install python3-venv python3-pip
```

Comment: This works for me. first **sudo apt install python3-venv python3-pip** then pip3 install wheel

Answer (score 2):

As @frmdstryr said, you can just use the following command.

```
pip install wheel
```

Answer (score 1):

Not related to Travis CI but
I ran into similar problem trying to install `jupyter` on my Mac OSX 10.8.5, and none of the other answers was of help. The problem was caused by building the "wheel" for the package called `pyzmq`, with error messages filling hundreds of pages.

The solution I found was to directly install an older version of that package:

```
python -m pip install pyzmq==17 --user
```

After that, the installation of `jupyter` succeded without errors.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ubuntu 18.04 this problem can be resolved by installing the `python3-wheel`package.

Usually this is installed as a dependency on any Python package. But especially when building container images you often work with `--no-install-recommends` and therefore it is often missing and has to be installed manually first.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the above works for you, perhaps you are experiencing the same problem that I did. I was only seeing this error when attempting to install `pyspark`. The solution is explained in this other stackoverflow question [unable to install pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51500288/unable-to-install-pyspark).

I post this b/c it wasn't immediately obvious to me from the error message that my issue was stemming solely from `pyspark`'s dependency on `pypandoc` and I'm hoping to save others from hours of head scratching! =)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the `pip install wheel` instruction given above, but it didn't work because I was told that the requirement was already satisfied. It turned out that I was using python-3.10 and pip from my python-3.9 site packages. I finally realized that by entering `python --version` and `pip --version` and comparing the directories.

With this realization, I installed a new version of pip to go with my python-3.10, installed the wheel, and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

as @Philippe Remy mention,
should import from `setuptools`

```
from setuptools import setup
```

reference: Official doc https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

### For the project's own environment and custom setup.py file will be this way

#### Activate environment

```bash
python -m venv venv or python3 -m venv venv

Mac/Linux
. /venv/env/activate

Windows

.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

#### setup.py file

```bash
 install_requires=["wheel >= x.x.x",],
 extras_require={
      "dev": [" "],
 },

pip install .
```

### Or use

```bash
pip install wheel
```

#### and finally use your command

```bash
python setup.py bdist_wheel
or
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Comment: `python setup.py bdist_wheel` is deprecated: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/setup-py-deprecated/