# Problems installing Pyephem on Synology DSM

Tags: python, linux, pyephem, synology

I'm trying to install Pyephem onto my Synology Box, which is running DSM6, and have run into some problems concerning wheel.   I have installed pip etc so have:

```
Installing collected packages: pip, six, pyparsing, packaging, appdirs, setuptools, wheel
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.1 packaging-16.8 pip-9.0.1 pyparsing-2.1.10 setuptools-34.2.0 six-1.10.0 wheel-0.29.0
```

but encounter this error when running pip install pyephem:

```
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyephem ... error
```

and later....

```
unable to execute '/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
error: command '/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

It seems related to [Why is python setup.py saying invalid command 'bdist_wheel' on Travis CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819221/why-is-python-setup-py-saying-invalid-command-bdist-wheel-on-travis-ci) which is something to do with older versions of wheel but I need a bit of directional help to move closer to a solution.

Thanks for your time etc.

Chris