# mesos 1.1.0 + Travis-CI: error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

Tags: python, travis-ci, mesos

I am developing a [mesos framework](https://github.com/MSO4SC/mesos-hpc-framework) in GitHub in which I want to use Travis-CI for continuous integration.

To do it I have a script in which I build and install mesos 1.1.0 in the travis VM. However the mesos install always fails with the error:

```
test "../.." = ".." ||          \
        (/bin/mkdir -p python/src/mesos && cp -pf ../../src/python/src/mesos/__init__.py python/src/mesos/__init__.py)
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
```

[This](https://github.com/MSO4SC/mesos-hpc-framework/blob/master/scripts/build-dependencies.sh) is the script I'm using to build & install mesos, and [this](https://github.com/MSO4SC/mesos-hpc-framework/blob/master/.travis.yml) is the simple .travis.yml file I'm using.

After googling I've added `- sudo -H pip install setuptools --upgrade` to the *travis.yml* file to resolve the problem, but no luck. Other solutions found didn't work either.

How could this problem be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34846776/1387612)

If you don't need python and Java bindings you can disable them by disbling them in configre step. This will save build time and should resolve python issues.

```
../configure --disable-python --disable-java
```

Comment: I already had tried the answer, but no luck. Thanks @janisz for your tip, indeed I didn't need java nor python and after disabling them mesos compiled. However I'm not going to accept the answer as it is does not resolve the problem in case python bindings are needed.

Comment: Take a look at this [PR](https://github.com/apache/mesos/pull/165) it adds travis build to Mesos repo. Maybe it helps you.