# unable to install pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to install pyspark as this:

```
python setup.py install
```

I get this error:

```
Could not import pypandoc - required to package PySpark
```

pypandoc is installed already

Any ideas how can I install pyspark?

Answer (score 43):

I faced the same issue and solved it as below
install pypandoc before installing pyspark

```
pip install pypandoc
pip install pyspark
```

Comment: This worked for me: Python 3.7.3, pip 20.1.1, Windows 10.0.17134 Build 17134, and running commands in Windows Powershell.

Comment: In my case I have Python3.8 installed (Ubuntu 20.04) and running `pip3 install pypandoc` (after running `sudo apt install python3-pip`) solved the problem

Comment: this is still working as of today. Spent 4 hours trying everything under the moon last night, and nothing worked until this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Try installing pypandoc with python3 with `pip3 install pypandoc`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using window follow the following steps:
1) install Jdk in the computer from link: `https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html`

2) set the environment variable `$JAVA_HOME= /path/where/you/installed/jdk`
than add path in the `PATH=%JAVA_HOME/bin`

3)download the spark from the link:- https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html 
this file in the Zip format extract the file and file name is like spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz , move this folder to the C Directory. and set the environment variable

```
SPARK_HOME=/path/of the /spark
```

4)download the scala ide from the link :- `http://scala-ide.org/`
extract the file and copy the Eclipse folder to the C: directory

5) now open cmd and write `spark-shell`
it will open the scala shell for you.

Answer (score 1):

**2018 version-**

Install `PYSPARK` on Windows 10 `JUPYTER-NOTEBOOK` with `ANACONDA NAVIGATOR`.

### STEP 1

**Download Packages**

1) spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz [Download](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)

2) Java JDK 8 version [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

3) Anaconda v 5.2 [Download](https://www.anaconda.com/download/)

4) scala-2.12.6.msi [Download](http://scala-2.12.6.msi)

5) hadoop v2.7.1 [Download](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.7.1)

### STEP 2

Create **SPARK** folder in **C:/** drive and extract `Hadoop`, `spark` and 
install `Scala` using **scala-2.12.6.msi** in the same directory. The directory structure should be
[It will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsTrv.png)

**Note: During installation of SCALA, specify C:/Spark folder**

### STEP 3

Now set the windows environment variables:

1. `HADOOP_HOME=C:\spark\hadoop`
2. `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151`
3. `SCALA_HOME=C:\spark\scala\bin`
4. `SPARK_HOME=C:\spark\spark\bin`
5. `PYSPARK_PYTHON=C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe`
6. `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter.exe`
7. `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook`
8. **NOW SELECT PATH OF SPARK** :

   Click on Edit and add New

   Add "**C:\spark\spark\bin**” to variable “Path” Windows

### STEP 4

- Make folder where you want to store Jupyter-Notebook outputs and files
- After that open Anaconda command prompt and **cd Folder name**
- then enter **Pyspark**

thats it your browser will pop up with Juypter localhost

### STEP 5

Check if `PySpark` is working or not !

Type simple code and run it

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
a = Row(name = 'Vinay' , age=22 , height=165)
print("a: ",a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install PySpark API for jupyter notebook:

1. Go to this site https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html to download latest spark. The file will be downloaded in .tgz format.
   Extract this tgz file in a directory where you want to install PySpark.
2. After extracting the tgz file , you will need to download hadoop because Apache spark requires Hadoop, 
   so download hadoop from https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/blob/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin/winutils.exe,
   A file will be downloaded - 'winutils.exe'. Copy this exe file in the 'bin/' directory of your spark (spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin)
3. If you have anaconda installed, there will be .condarc file in C:\Users\, open that, change ssl_verify from true to false.
   This will help you to install python libraries directly from prompt.(In case if you have restricted network)
4. Open anaconda prompt and type 'conda install findspark' to install findspark python module.If you are not able to install it, go to this link
   https://github.com/minrk/findspark and download ZIP,extract it and open anaconda prompt and go to this extracted path and run 'python setup.py install'.
5. Open ThisPC>> Properties>> Advanced System Settings(You need to have admin access for that).Click on Environment Variables and then 
   Add new user environment variables.
   [image: Environment variables to add]
6. After creating 4 user variables and adding spark path to 'PATH' system variable, open jupyter notebook and run this code:

   ```
   import findspark
   findspark.init()
   import pyspark
   from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
   from pyspark import SparkContext    

   sc = SparkContext("local", "First App")
   sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
   ```

   If you dont get any error, the installation has been completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me (windows 10) was:

1. install pypandoc with pip install pypandoc
2. add wheel to PATH in windows - if you do pip install wheel and see yellow warning message (wheel not installed not in ... which is not in your PATH) then try doing that. Indication of this problem will be a message during pyspark installation which saying that setup.py is used because wheel is unavailable (it is unavailable because it is not in PATH)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me inside docker was actually done in three steps:

```
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install pypandoc
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-input
```

Or shorter:

```
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install pypandoc && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt --no-input
```

Answer (score -4):

As of version 2.2 you can directly install pyspark using pip

```
pip install pyspark
```