# Apache Airflow PythonVirtualenvOperator Failed building wheel for df2gspread

Tags: python, virtualenv, airflow

I'm trying to schedule python script using apache airflow and my script requires extra packages. 
So I'm using PythonVirtualenvOperator, but script exits trying to install df2gspread package. Here is  an example.

Content of DAG

```
import time
from pprint import pprint

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonVirtualenvOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test_example',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    tags=['example']
)


def callable_virtualenv():
    from colorama import Fore
    from time import sleep
    import df2gspread
    print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        sleep(1)
    print('Finished')


virtualenv_task = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id="virtualenv_python",
    python_callable=callable_virtualenv,
    requirements=[
        "colorama==0.4.0",
        "df2gspread==1.0.4",
    ],
    system_site_packages=False,
    python_version='3.7',
    dag=dag,
)
```

And result of running this DAG is

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for df2gspread
```

Colorama is installed without any problems and at the same time df2gspread raises the error

UPD:Here is complete output of install command

```
  Building wheels for collected packages: df2gspread
  Building wheel for df2gspread (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for df2gspread (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/_z/6v0wj4dj7kldx67qgnw4m3640000gn/T/pip-install-2xx3cr8h/df2gspread/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/_z/6v0wj4dj7kldx67qgnw4m3640000gn/T/pip-install-2xx3cr8h/df2gspread/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/_z/6v0wj4dj7kldx67qgnw4m3640000gn/T/pip-wheel-yu4021ye
       cwd: /private/var/folders/_z/6v0wj4dj7kldx67qgnw4m3640000gn/T/pip-install-2xx3cr8h/df2gspread/
  Complete output (6 lines):
  usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: setup.py --help-commands
     or: setup.py cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for df2gspread
  Running setup.py clean for df2gspread
Failed to build df2gspread
Installing collected packages: colorama, argparse, uritemplate, httplib2, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, rsa, six, oauth2client, google-api-python-client, chardet, urllib3, idna, certifi, requests, gspread, python-dateutil, pytz, numpy, pandas, df2gspread
  WARNING: The scripts pyrsa-decrypt, pyrsa-encrypt, pyrsa-keygen, pyrsa-priv2pub, pyrsa-sign and pyrsa-verify are installed in '/var/folders/_z/6v0wj4dj7kldx67qgnw4m3640000gn/T/venvcmzzx47t/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script chardetect is installed in '/var/folders/_z/6v0wj4dj7kldx67qgnw4m3640000gn/T/venvcmzzx47t/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py3 and f2py3.7 are installed in '/var/folders/_z/6v0wj4dj7kldx67qgnw4m3640000gn/T/venvcmzzx47t/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
    Running setup.py install for df2gspread: started
    Running setup.py install for df2gspread: finished with status 'done'
```

Comment: is that the only output? there should be more (an error message, etc. about building)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44862371/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+error%3A+invalid+command+bdist_wheel