# How and who should specify wheel as a Python package dependency?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel, python-packaging

I'm writing a source bundle (not a fully packaged module, but some scripts with dependencies) to be installed and executed inside a framework application (Specifically, Amazon SageMaker's [TensorFlow serving container](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving-container) - running Python 3.5).

One of my dependencies is `matplotlib`, which in turn needs `kiwisolver`, which has C++ components.

It seems like my target container doesn't have `wheel` installed by default, because when I supply just a `requirements.txt` file I get the error described in ["Why is python setup.py saying invalid command 'bdist_wheel' on Travis CI?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819221/why-is-python-setup-py-saying-invalid-command-bdist-wheel-on-travis-ci).

I think I got it working by supplying a `setup.py` instead, with `setup_requires=["wheel"]` as advised in the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54833684) to that Travis CI question.

My Python packaging-fu is weak, so my question is: Who **should** be specifying this dependency, because it seems like it shouldn't be me?

- Should kiwisolver be advertising that it needs `wheel`?
- Does a framework application/environment installing user code modules via `requirements.txt` have an implicit contract to make `wheel` available in the environment, for some reason in Python's packaging ethos?
- Maybe it really is on me to know that, since I'm indirectly consuming a module like kiwisolver, my package requires `wheel` for setup and a straight `pip install -r requirements.txt` won't work?

Even better if somebody can explain whether this answer is changing with [PEP 518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) and the deprecation of `setup_requires` :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually *wheel* could be considered a *build-time* dependency and not an *install-time* dependency. But actually, *wheel* is just a way of distributing Python projects (libraries or applications), so it usually isn't a mandatory dependency.

The one system building the library (*kiwisolver*) might have a need to have the *wheel* tool installed. But if I am not mistaken recent versions of *pip* have *wheel* already bundled in, so nowadays there is often no need to install it explicitly.

In many cases there are *wheels* already built available on *PyPI*. But sometimes there are no *wheels* compatible with the target system (Python interpreter version, operating system, CPU bitness). In your case here, [*kiwisolver* has a wide range of *wheels* available but not for *Python 3.5*](https://pypi.org/project/kiwisolver/1.2.0/#files).

So it seems like the system you want to install *kiwisolver* on, is not compatible with any of the *wheels* available on *PyPI*. So *pip* has to build it locally. Usually *pip* tries to build a *wheel* first, but as far as I know it's not a deal-breaker if a *wheel* cannot be built then *pip* usually just continues and installs the project without going to the *wheel* intermediary step.

But still *pip* has to be able to *build* the library, which might require some C/C++ compilers or that other unusual conditions are met on the local system. Which is why distributing libraries as *wheel* is very comfortable, since the *build* step is already done.

So to sum it up, from my point of view, no one really has to declare *wheel* as a dependency or install *wheel* unless they actually want to build *wheels*. But *wheel* really is just an intermediary optional step. It's a way of distributing Python projects (libraries or applications). I don't see the *absolute need* for adding *wheel* to *setuptools*' `setup_requires` (which is *deprecated* or on close to it) nor to `pyproject.toml`'s `build-system.requires`, it's more of a (very common, and quasi standard) convenience.

Now what would I do in your situation?

- Before installing from the `requirements.txt` file that contains *kiwisolver* (directly or indirectly) either make sure that *pip* is up-to-date or explicitly install *wheel*, and:

  - Use a version of Python for which *wheels* are already available on *PyPI*.
  - If you want to stay on *Python 3.5*:

    - Make sure the target system is able to build *kiwisolver* itself (maybe it requires a C/C++ compiler plus some other native libraries).