# How to run bdist_wheel on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: docker, pip, ubuntu-18.04, python-wheel

I've got a small Dockerfile where I'm trying to get to a point where I can `RUN pip3 bdist_wheel` successfully. That is, without getting this error:

> unknown command "bdist_wheel" - maybe you meant "wheel"

I've tried installing everything mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59596814/96588), but no luck.

Minimal repro Dockerfile and [`docker build` output](https://pastebin.com/YHgsCFmk):

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -qyy -o APT::Install-Recommends=false -o APT::Install-Suggests=false \
    file \
    gcc \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    python3-venv \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip3 install --cache-dir=/tmp/pipcache --upgrade pip && rm -rf /tmp/pipcache
RUN pip install --cache-dir=/tmp/pipcache poetry && rm -rf /tmp/pipcache

WORKDIR /src/app
RUN poetry new .
RUN poetry add gevent
```

The most relevant part of the output is of course

> error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

Comment: @phd Nope, I've tried `apt-get install python3-wheel`, `pip install wheel`, `pip install --upgrade wheel` and probably some other variations.

Comment: I tried that too. For now I'm capitulating and upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 to get away from this horrible situation.

Comment: There's no `pip bdist_wheel` command. Either `pip wheel`, or `python setup.py bdist_wheel` from inside the repo.

Comment: @hoefling Tell that to the gevent maintainers. I'm just trying to install the latest gevent package.

Comment: Can you point to exact spot featuring this "command"? Is it a Dockerfile in gevent repo?

Comment: I see, it's a Dockerfile you've got - it's clearly wrong, there's nothing wrong with `gevent`. Post the minimal Dockerfile reproducing the error.

Comment: @hoefling Here you go, minimal Dockerfile + output.

Answer (score 3):

First, some notes to the `error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'` output. When running `pip install <pkgname>`, `pip` will try to find a prebuilt wheel that matches your target platform. If it doesn't find one, it tries to build a wheel itself -- the source dist is downloaded and `pip wheel` is run to produce the wheel. On success, the built wheel is installed. On any failure (the `wheel` package not installed, `python setup.py bdist_wheel` failed or whatever), `pip` will fallback to the second option, which is the `distutils` installation method: running `python setup.py install` over the unpacked source dist. This is what you can observe in the log you posted:

```
Failed building wheel for gevent
...
Running setup.py install for gevent: started
```

Only when the `setup.py install` also fails, the installation is failed unconditionally. So while `pip` can't indeed build the wheel b/c the `wheel` package is not installed, it is not an issue for the failing installation. You can fix this by adding `wheel` to development packages:

```
RUN poetry add --dev wheel
RUN poetry add gevent
```

but this is an optional thing and won't affect the build result.

Now, to the real error:

```
Running '(cd  "/tmp/pip-build-ek9pxyw2/gevent/deps/libev"  && sh ./configure -C > configure-output.txt )' in /tmp/pip-build-ek9pxyw2/gevent
    config.status: error: in `/tmp/pip-build-ek9pxyw2/gevent/deps/libev':
    config.status: error: Something went wrong bootstrapping makefile fragments
        for automatic dependency tracking.  Try re-running configure with the
        '--disable-dependency-tracking' option to at least be able to build
        the package (albeit without support for automatic dependency tracking).
    See `config.log' for more details
```

`Something went wrong bootstrapping makefile fragments` usually means that you're missing `make`. Install it in addition to the rest:

```
RUN apt install -y make
```

After doing that and rerunning the build, I've got the last error

```
error: src/gevent/libev/corecext.c: No such file or directory
```

This is because `gevent` needs Cython for generating the C extension sources. Install it before installing `gevent`:

```
RUN poetry add --dev cython
RUN poetry add gevent
```

The complete Dockerfile for reference, changes in bold:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -qyy -o APT::Install-Recommends=false -o APT::Install-Suggests=false \
    file \
    gcc \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    python3-venv \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip3 install --cache-dir=/tmp/pipcache --upgrade pip && rm -rf /tmp/pipcache
RUN pip install --cache-dir=/tmp/pipcache poetry && rm -rf /tmp/pipcache

WORKDIR /src/app
RUN poetry new .


RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y make
RUN poetry add --dev wheel cython


RUN poetry add gevent
```

Neither `wheel` nor `cython` are required to actually run `gevent`, so they can be safely uninstalled afterwards to reduce the image size.