# Why do I get the error 'invalid command:bdist_wheel' while installing pyautogui?

Tags: python, pip, pyautogui

Novice programmer here. I've been getting the following error while trying to install pyautogui:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'C:\Users\YİĞİT\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\YT28B4~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7qf151s6'
> cwd: C:\Users\YİĞİT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2ntrh3to\pymsgbox
> Complete output (14 lines):
> running dist_info
> creating C:\Users\YİĞİT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-2w36_w_e\PyMsgBox.egg-info
> writing C:\Users\YİĞİT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-2w36_w_e\PyMsgBox.egg-info\PKG-INFO
> writing dependency_links to C:\Users\YİĞİT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-2w36_w_e\PyMsgBox.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
> writing top-level names to C:\Users\YİĞİT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-2w36_w_e\PyMsgBox.egg-info\top_level.txt
> writing manifest file 'C:\Users\YİĞİT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-2w36_w_e\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> reading manifest file 'C:\Users\YİĞİT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-2w36_w_e\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
> Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
> warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'pymsgbox'
> writing manifest file 'C:\Users\YİĞİT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-2w36_w_e\PyMsgBox.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> creating 'C:\Users\YİĞİT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-2w36_w_e\PyMsgBox.dist-info'
> error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
> ----------------------------------------
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\YİĞİT\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\YT28B4~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7qf151s6' Check the logs for full command output.

Some of the solutions I've come across are to install wheel and to modify setup.py. Wheel is installed, but I can't find setup.py. What should I do?

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819221/why-is-python-setup-py-saying-invalid-command-bdist-wheel-on-travis-ci

Comment: not really. it says the solution is to install wheel, but i've already done that. after that, there are some solutions regarding modifying the setup.py file, but i can't even find it.

Comment: Not sure but run your CMD as admin then activate your virtual enviroment and run `pip install pipwin` then `pipwin install pyautogui`. Worth attempting, sorry if It doesn't work.

Comment: Or, if you have a it installed, try installing it with anaconda. Other Ideas, perhaps an older/newer version of python may work, I see you are on 3.8, perhaps that is the issue it runs fine for me on 3.9 and 3.7