# pip install apache-beam fails with Building wheels for collected packages

Tags: apache-beam

## Problem

```
$ pip3 install apache-beam
...
Building wheels for collected packages: future, avro-python3, docopt
  Building wheel for future (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4aondmrw/future/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4aondmrw/future/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-5uobb0_9
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-4aondmrw/future/
  Complete output (6 lines):
  usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: setup.py --help-commands
     or: setup.py cmd --help
  
  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for future
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

- [hy is python setup.py saying invalid command 'bdist_wheel' on Travis CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44862371/4281353)

```
pip3 install wheel
```

Fixed the issue.

```
$ pip3 install apache-beam
...
Successfully built avro-python3
Installing collected packages: avro-python3, pyasn1, rsa, pyasn1-modules, oauth2client, apache-beam
Successfully installed apache-beam-2.32.0 avro-python3-1.9.2.1 oauth2client-4.1.3 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 rsa-4.7.2
```