# AssertionError inside of ensure_local_distutils when building a PyInstaller exe using setuptools/distutils

Tags: python, pyinstaller, setuptools, distutils

**I am trying to convert some Python code into an `.exe` with PyInstaller**. My code uses distutils, which has already caused me some head scratching in the past as it seems to duplicate setuptools functionality, and interacts with it strangely. It e.g. requires [an **unused** import of setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50314071/2111778) to work properly which seems very unpythonic to me.

I need to use both packages inside my project. I import both packages in the order `import setuptools; import distutils` because the other order throws a warning which is already worrying.

**My script runs fine but after I turn it into an exe I get a traceback inside of the suspicious `_distutils_hack` submodule of setuptools.** And yes it just prints a file name with no context.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  <18 lines omitted>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "_distutils_hack\override.py", line 71, in <module>
  File "_distutils_hack\__init__.py", line 71, in do_override
  File "_distutils_hack\__init__.py", line 59, in ensure_local_distutils
AssertionError: C:\Users\<omitted>\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI294562\distutils\core.pyc
```

I am using

- `Python 3.7.7 on win32` (but I reproduced it with 3.8, 3.9, and 3.10)
- `pyinstaller==4.8` (Jan 2022) for Windows
- `distutils==3.7.7` (built-in)
- `setuptools==60.5.0` (Jan 2022)

Apparently, `setuptools` is listed on PyPI and thus upgradable, but `distutils` is not listed on PyPI and thus not upgradable (the version is bundled with Python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported my issue to the `setuptools` project, but then the `PyInstaller` project stepped in to include [a workaround on their side](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6911). Now any release starting from `5.4` should work!

```bash
pip install pyinstaller>=5.4
```

Answer (score 6):

A workaround I found was downgrading to

```bash
pip install setuptools==59.8.0
```

I [reported this issue](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3089) to the project and then confirmed the bug was introduced in `setuptools==60.0.0`. I'll update this question when I find out more, or it gets fixed.