# Error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel' with setuptools==67.1.0

Tags: python, pypi

I'm getting tje following error after having upgraded `setuptools` to version 67.1.0:

```
% python setup.py bdist_wheel
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
```

Have others come across this issue? The error was not there before the upgrade.

Within my `setup.py`, I have

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import setuptools

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setuptools.setup()
```

and the version of `wheel` is 0.38.4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is python setup.py saying invalid command 'bdist\_wheel' on Travis CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819221/why-is-python-setup-py-saying-invalid-command-bdist-wheel-on-travis-ci)

Comment: I've tried everything listed in the link including uninstalling a re-installing `wheel` but this didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: There isn't enough info here to give different answers than in the linked question. If you post the commands you are trying to run and all of the error output, might be able to spot why the solutions did not work.

Comment: to elaborate: please talk about which version of python you're using, whether you've already installed `wheel` first (and if so, plain pip or python -m pip?), whether you've tried using a virtual environment, and how you got `setup.py` in your working dir. Because all those things affect what a solution looks like.

Comment: I'm using a virtual environment set up under `python==3.10.6` and have installed `wheel` by `pip install wheel`. I've also tried `pip install --upgrade wheel`.

Comment: The package I'm trying to upload a distribution is here: https://github.com/roxyboy/xwavelet .